# Cookies and SameSite + Secure - ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

The following warning is being shown in the console, even though I have the following settings on my express application. Has anyone seen this error before? My search brought me to https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3095

I am also using express : 4.17.1

```
let COOKIE_OPTIONS = { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true };
```

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://MYURL.URL was set
without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver 
cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and 
`Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under 
Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

When doing a request using Insomia (Postman) I see the following

```
access_token=someToken; 
Path=/; 
HttpOnly; 
Secure; 
SameSite=None
```

Comment: Issue might be related to serving the cookies over HTTPS instead of HTTP which I currently am..

Comment: Tested and found it works for HTTP as well.

Answer (score 23):

Documentation Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookiesamesite

The below code will solve your issue. This is also recommended going forward.

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();

const sessionConfig = {
  secret: 'MYSECRET',
  name: 'appName',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: store,
  cookie : {
    sameSite: 'strict', // THIS is the config you are looking for.
  }
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
  sessionConfig.cookie.secure = true; // serve secure cookies
}

app.use(session(sessionConfig));
```

In your case, set `sameSite` to `'none'`

In case you are wondering what is `store`? I am using my database as storage for all the cookies. It's not relevant to the question asked by OP. Just added as pointed by @klevis in the comment. Here's the code:

```
const KnexSessionStore = require('connect-session-knex')(session);
const store = new KnexSessionStore({
  tablename: 'session',
  knex: kx,
  createtable: false
});
```

- Edit 1: Fixed issue pointed out by **CaptainAdmin**
- Edit 2: Added store definition.

Comment: There is no property like sameSite for session config, it's for cookie

Comment: @CaptainZero have fixed the same. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 12):

You can set these options without using any node package.. With Express Only
Like this:

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    //.....Other Code
    res.cookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', { sameSite: 'none', secure: true})
    //.....Other Code
})
```

Comment: Worked for me thank you! I am now able to save cookies on a browser from my API server. Before this setting I was only able to save on Postman and it was driving me mad!

Answer (score 2):

As far I kwon, this is a warning about new implementation for chrome in the future

> samesite option on cookies: Starting in Chrome 80, cookies that do not specify a SameSite attribute will be treated as if they were SameSite=Lax with the additional behavior that they will still be included in POST requests to ease the transition for existing sites.

Any further information: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site

If you desire to test your web page, this article explains how to set Chrome flags for testing. If your page stops working you have to check all request and see for "http://" to "https://" updates or check third-party cookies