# CORS: Cookies are not sent or received by the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, axios, cross-domain

I have an issue whereby my login cookie is not being sent to the browser (nor sent back to the server) when I am in production (netlify front, heroku back). When React and Express are ran locally, it is fine - and I can see CORS allows requests to be made and cookies sent back OK.

Weirdly, in production, POSTMAN is able to login and receive a cookie OK. It's just React, when ran both locally and when deployed, the request is made to the deployed production server, but a cookie is not sent back. (My production env variable on Heroku is set to "production" and origin should determine this to be the case in the CORS code below.)

My CORS configuration in my express app is:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

let origin = 'http://192.168.1.132:3000'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   origin = 'https://appname.app'
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
);

next();
});

app.use(cors({ origin: origin, credentials: 'true' }));
```

My requests in React look like:

```js
axios
.post(
    `${serverURL}/signin`,
           {
              email: emailInput,
              password: passInput,
              client: 'React',
           },

           {
              withCredentials: true,
              credentials: 'include',
           }
     ).then((response) => {
          // handles response
                
          });
```

Can anyone see anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Anything appearing in the console regarding cors error?

Comment: No errors in the console at all re. CORS.

Comment: In the network tab, you see the request go out and what response does it receive?

Comment: It received nothing. Once the signin button has been pressed, it redirects to a page where a checkuser request is also made, which checks if there is a cookie and returns the data based on the cookie. However, that cookie when logged in is never set (it works locally, but not when deployed). The checkuser request sends back a message saying no cookie found

Comment: So I turned off the re-direct in order to see the signin request like you said (sorry i should have done it earlier!) and it actually blocked the cookie due to: The Set-Cookie didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was defaulted to "SameSite=Lax", and was blocked because it came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with "SameSite=None" to enable cross-site usage. -- Do you know where in my code (front or back) do i need to inset a samesite=none? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Hey no problem, I've had trouble with CORS issues in the past, I now how tricky it can be. The SameSite attribute is set on the server, so in this case it's your express app. I'm not very familiar with express (I use Laravel as a backend most of the time) but I'm sure setting that attribute in express is fairly common. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228871/cookies-and-samesite-secure-expressjs

Comment: Thanks Nick, I shall check it out. Great help